# How do i show date of birth input fields in a vertical form in bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[here is my code:](http://jsbin.com/uLaWIqu/1/edit)

what i want is the *date of birth* label to be on top of the *day and month* fields just as the *Marital Status* label is arranged.How do i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you add a `<br />` after your `Date of Birth` Label, you can see that your 3 `div` elements for month, day, year center on the next line, because they only add up to 7 rather than 12.  if you want them to span the entire row, they need to add up to 12.

Essentially, the use of `<div>` within your form is short circuiting the normal form flow, so you either need a `<br />` or you need to enclose the 3 smaller `<div>` elements inside another `<div>` which spans the entire row.

Comment: tried my friend, label still on the same lin. if i add up to 12, then Year field jumbs down.

Comment: correct, because `<div>` does not force a line break, but the `<select>` does because of it's width... you need the `<br />` after your label since your next element does not force a line break

Comment: yes, that worked. but i wrapped the label inside a col-md-12. but still there is an intent issue for the second row.i updated it
[here](http://jsbin.com/uLaWIqu/6/edit)

Comment: I assume you mean indent, and that's because the bootstrap col classes have padding built in.  if you are using them, you should use them everywhere or nowhere, or override their padding. i.e. style="padding: 0px"